# Code works in Geany IDE, but segmentation fault in HackerRanks. What's the technical reason for this?

Tags: c

It's a simple program that initializes 3 data types and takes 3 inputs, an int, a double, and a string. Then perform addition on the numbers and prints out the "concatenated" string (doesn't actually have to be concatenated). It works in Geany IDE running on a VM of Ubuntu 16.04, but gets a segmentation fault in HackerRank. Why would this occur?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    char s[] = "HackerRank ";
    int j, cnt = 0;
    double e;
    char c[100];
    char ch;

    scanf(" %d", &j);
    scanf(" %lf", &e);
    ch = getchar();
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){
        c[cnt++] = ch;
    }
    c[cnt] = '\0';
    printf("%d\n", i+j);
    printf("%.1lf\n", d+e);
    printf("%s%s\n", s, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The "technical reason" is most likely because of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Have you tried adding some *bounds checking* for the insertion into `c`? Remember that C doesn't have any bounds checking for arrays.

Comment: I bet more than 100 chars in the input. And you write outside the bounds

Comment: Are you sure a newline will terminate the input? Check for `EOF` as well, but you must change `char ch;` to `int ch;` I would use `while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)` Without a newline, you'll break the array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude not sure I understand, I am seemingly not defining anything that even approaches the bounds. The c array is only 100 chars

Comment: @WeatherVane it does when I run it in my Ubuntu VM, in Geany IDE. What do you mean "break the array"?

Comment: I mean "exceed the **bounds** of the array `c[]`" since without a newline the loop continues until you break something.

Comment: Usually these challenge sites redirect a file to the input of your program. A text file does not have to end with a newline.

Comment: One major problem with many sites such as HackerRank is that they don't tell you the exact input. Without the exact input it becomes very hard to debug. If the input from HackerRank is flawed in any way (possibly on purpose), or perhaps not exactly what you expect, then you will have plenty of problems. Like possibly reading more than 99 characters into the array `a`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I see. So is that an assumption I should make? Is it trial and error to check how their files are formatted or should I basically write code that knows how to satisfy both scenarios?

Comment: I would say the latter.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude *they don't tell you the exact input* That's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: *Is it trial and error to check how their files are formatted* No, you should *carefully* read the assignment and implement *exactly* what it says. If it says your program should read a string, it should read a string. Not a string shorter than 100 characters. Not a string shorter than 1000000 characters. A string.